# Export modifier, not apply

Tags: python, modifiers, export, add-on

I'm making an exporter for Blender to Metasequoia. (the import while come later)
Metasequoia 3d file are compatible with modifier like mirror and subdivision surface
I really don't want to apply them if it's possible
I found nothing about it in google or blender API
go see what I've done so far https://github.com/50thomatoes50/blender.io_mqo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to the author of each exporter to support exporting a modified mesh.

Some exporters for example, could export without applying Subdivision-Surface, but use some option in the format that denotes the object as having it enabled (RenderMan RIB is one that can do this, Lightwave also supports).

But in most cases the format doesn't support Blender's modifiers natively, its typically good if the exporter can write the data you see in the viewport/render (WYSIWYG).

All Blender's bundled exporters support this, so there are enough examples of how to implement this.

Comment: I can't find what you're talking about. I'm working with blender 2.69. there isn't an exporter for Renderman (tryed RIB mosaic) and the lightwave exporter don't export the modifier

Comment: The bundled exporters provide an option to apply modifiers or not, but I don't know of any that exports meshes without modifiers applied + meta information about the modifier settings.

Comment: @user2030 My point is that some formats happen support features close enough to Blender's modifiers natively, so in that case it makes sense not to write the modified data. But these cases are not so common.

I double checked and LWO for 2.49 supported subsurf on import only (not export), corrected reply.